# How to check screen ON time in Windows 11?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11

Haven't found a way to check screen on time in Windows 11. In MacOS there is Screen Time which gives useful information regarding screen time, application time usage etc. Is there something that is the same in Windows?

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically?

Comment: No just find it as a regular user, no coding

Comment: Then you should ask on Super User, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **settings**. Click on the system tab, then scroll down to **power and battery**. Click it and then expand "battery usage" section.

Here you will see a chart showing 24h battery usage of your PC. Just below this chart you will find the screen on time, screen off time, and the total sleep time.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Task Manager's App history tab (https://www.digitalcitizen.life/task-manager-app-history/). You could also try using Family Safety (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/set-screen-time-limits-on-your-kids-devices-a593d725-fc4c-044c-284d-32eab0305ffd, https://robots.net/how-to-guide/how-to-track-your-screen-time-on-pc-and-mac/, https://screentimelabs.com/windows-parental-controls-family-security/, https://www.gizbot.com/how-to/tips-tricks/how-to-check-screen-time-on-various-devices-064361.html) or AppLocker (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/monitor-application-usage-with-applocker).